# add extra tag/ field to asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have ASP.NET 3.5 webform which got dropdownlist. Number of DropdownList can various. Now I want extra tag or field "ElementClinicalID" to dropdownlist like id, name; that I can assign uniqueRecordID to it. I am attending to read this uniqueRecordID later on in javascript or jquery and i dont need to show thhis valie on webpage.

```
            DropDownList ddlProcedureGrade = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlProcedureGrade");
            ddlProcedureGrade.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlProcedureGrade.DataValueField = "ID";

            ddlProcedureGrade.DataSource = clinicalProcedureElementGradeDetails;
            ddlProcedureGrade.DataBind();
            ddlProcedureGrade.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem());
```

so I want add tage ElementClinicalID= clinicalElement().ID; ??????????????????

I want in html following result

```
<select id="ctl00_ContentArea_rptProcedure_ctl01_ddlProcedureGrade" name="ctl00$ContentArea$rptProcedure$ctl01$ddlProcedureGrade" ElementClinicalID="273" >
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Excellent</option>
<option value="2">Satisfactory</option>
<option value="3">Borderline</option>
<option value="4">Unsatisfactory</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Attributes` property. Try this:

```
ddlProcedureGrade.Attributes["ElementClinicalID"] = clinicalElement().ID;
```